# How can I combine two xacros with a common root?

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two XACROs for two robotic arms and I want them in the same XACRO, so that the URDF generated from that XACRO contains both those arms. The issue is that both the arms' XACROs start from a "Root" and it's not allowing me to do that.

So how can I add the two with both having the same "Root" for reference?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70753/how-can-i-combine-two-xacros-with-a-common-root?/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2013-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer is that you can't. You can't have two links with the same name.

Check out [This bit of tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File#Leg_macro)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-08-02**:
Thanks @David Lu. I did see that. And have already started modifying the files accordingly. Only issue is that these files rely on lots of "Properties" and trying to duplicate the information is a bit tedious. I keep getting errors. Working on that. Thanks again.